# Return values from nested `selectInput` inside shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

I am having problems with nested `selectInput`s inside a `shiny` module.

Consider the following minimal sample app

```r
library(shiny)

options <- list(A = 1:3, B = 4:6)

module_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        selectInput(ns("option1"), "Option 1", choices = LETTERS[1:2]),
        selectInput(ns("option2"), "Option 2", choices = NULL))
}
    
module_server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) { 
            observe({
                updateSelectInput(
                    session, "option2", choices = options[[input$option1]])
            })
            return(list(
                option1 = reactive(input$option1),
                option2 = reactive(input$option2)))
        }
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    module_ui("module"),
    textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    sel <- module_server("module")
    output$text <- renderText({
        req(sel$option1(), sel$option2())
        print(paste0(sel$option1(), sel$option2(), collape = ""))
        paste0(sel$option1(), sel$option2(), collape = "")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My problem can be reproduced when doing the following:

1. Keep entry "A" from "Option 1" and entry "1" from "Option 2" (entries for "Option 2" are based on the currently selected entry from "Option 1").
2. Then select entry "B" from "Option 1".

This does not immediately clear and update the list entries in "Option 2". Instead, for a short time, the `reactive` return values from `module_server` give the non-existent "Option 1"-"Option 2" combination "B1" (see the terminal output in the sample app); this happens only very briefly before the entries in "Option 2" are then correctly updated via `updateSelectInput`. The issue is that any non-existent value combination that is returned by the module causes issues/errors downstream.

The post [Dealing with nested selectizeInputs and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404942/dealing-with-nested-selectizeinputs-and-modules) describes a very similar problem but I find the solution problematic in my case. Amongst other things, I'd like the module to handle validation of inputs.

I don't have this issue when I place the `selectInput`s in the main `ui` and use `updateSelectInput` in the main `server`. Somehow the two `reactive` elements in the return argument of `module_server` are "too quick". Is there a way to validate/check the inputs **prior to returning them** in `module_server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. You can explicitly do the validation with a `req()` in the second reactive output. i.e.

```
module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) { 
      observe({
        updateSelectInput(
          session, "option2", choices = options[[input$option1]])
      })
      
      return(list(
        option1 = reactive(input$option1),
        option2 = reactive({
          req(input$option2 %in% options[[input$option1]])
          input$option2
          })))
    }
  )
}
```

It'll basically stop anything downstream with that reactive until the condition is satisifed.

Comment: Yes, that does it! My only minor gripe with this is that it adds another call to `options[[input$option1]]`. In my actual case, `choices` gets populated from distinct entries in a reasonably large table of an SQLite database. This process takes a few seconds but was acceptable since it originally only happened when I changed "Option 1". Now with the additional `req` check, this happens also when changing "Option 2". A work-around is to create a lookup table in the SQLite db from which the `choices` can be extracted directly, making the `req` check much faster.